# google maps custom marker rotation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[google maps custom marker symbol example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom)

google maps api has an example showing custom marker symbol (a yellow start over australia) . On that star clickable area is much larger than a star itself. If i add a "shape" object with the same coordinates as the start to the marker clickable area becomes a star shape. following link is showing that:

[jsfiddle with star shaped clickable area](https://jsfiddle.net/tornike/kodc58Lo/)

```
`var markerShapeExact = {
coord:[125,5,155,90,245,90,175,145,200,230,125,180,50,230,75,145,5,90,95,90],
type: 'poly'
};
var goldStar = {
path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
fillColor: 'yellow',
fillOpacity: 0.8,
scale: 1,
strokeColor: 'gold',
strokeWeight: 14
//,rotation: 10
};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: map.getCenter(),
 icon: goldStar,
 shape: markerShapeExact,
 map: map
 });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
alert('hello maps');
 });`
```

so everything was ok so far. Now if I try to rotate the marker clickable are gets out of shape and i cannot understand what is wrong.
uncomenting the line ",rotation: 10" in that jsfiddle can show this behavior.

Can anyone tell me how to rotate a marker so that clickable area stays the same shape as the marker and follows marker's rotation?

thanks

Comment: not related to my question. I can rotate the marker the problem i described in the question is that clickable area is not rotating together with the marker. still have not found any solution unfortunately